# Upgrade python packages (Ubuntu) with pip: use "sudo" or "--user"?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I have a question about installing/upgrading Python packages using the tool `pip`.

I can either run

```
sudo pip install -U PACKAGENAME
```

or

```
pip install -U PACKAGENAME --user
```

What is the difference between those two commands and which one should I prefer...

1. on my own machine?
2. in the install script of a python program I publish?

Comment: Why would your install script be installing/upgrading directly? Just supply a `requirements.txt` and/or define the dependencies in `setup.py`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Although this was not the answer I waited for, it sounds interesting. I have not heard about this feature yet. Could you provide me a link or a manual on this? Anyway, I guess I will still have to decide whether to use sudo or --users to install the requirements.txt instead of each separate package.

Comment: Have a look at e.g. https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing.html. And no, you won't - in that case, whoever you distribute it to will run `pip install -r requirements.txt` with whatever settings they need.